# Paging page size in wijmo flexgrid not working in IE 7

Tags: wijmo, msflexgrid

In My Wijmo FlexGrid I have applied Paging (Grid height changing on page size changes).Its working fine in Chrome but not working In IE 7.

I have written the below code.

```
function PageSizing(pagerId, gridId, gridDataCollection) {

    var value = $('#' + pagerId).val();
    flexGrid.util.paging(value, gridDataCollection, '#' + gridId);

    $('#' + pagerId).on('change', function () {

        var value = $(this).val();
        flexGrid.util.paging(value, gridDataCollection, '#' + gridId);

    });
}
```

In Flexgrid.js below Code is Used.

paging: function (e, data, grid) {
            var pagesize = e;

```
        if (!pagesize) {
            pagesize = 0;
        } else {
            pagesize = wijmo.Globalize.parseInt(pagesize);
            data.pageSize = 0;
            data.refresh();
            if (pagesize == 5) {                    
                $(grid).css('max-height', '182px');
            }
            else if (pagesize == 10) {                    
                $(grid).css('max-height', '322px');
            }
            else if (pagesize == 15) {                    
                $(grid).css('max-height', '462px');
            }
            else if (pagesize == 20) {
                $(grid).css('max-height', '602px');
            }
            else if (pagesize == 25) {
                $(grid).css('max-height', '743px');
            }

        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Wijmo FlexGrid will not work in IE7 since its based on ECMAScript 5 and requires modern browsers i.e. IE9 or better. You can refer to the following link for more details:http://wijmo.com/5/docs/

Comment: Sorry mistake..i am using IE9 only..in IE9 paging Is not working

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to handle pageChanging event of CollectionView to change the height of the grid. Here is the doc link: http://wijmo.com/5/docs/topic/wijmo.collections.CollectionView.Class.html. If it does not help then share a fiddle demonstrating the issue.